# Find the : $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{i!}=\text{?}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the :
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i!}=\text{?}$$

For ex :

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{100}\dfrac{1}{i!}=\text{?}$$

---

My Try :

$$\frac{1}{2\times 1}+\frac{1}{1 \times 2 \times 3 }=\frac{3(1)+1}{1 \times 2 \times 3 }$$

$$\frac{4}{1 \times 2 \times 3 }+\frac{1}{1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 } = \frac{4(4)+1}{1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4}$$

$$\frac{17}{1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 }+\frac{1}{1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4\times 5 }=\frac{5(17)+1}{1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5}$$

Now what ?

Comment: Are you looking for a closed form? I don't think there is one. The limit is $e$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : It converges to $e-1$ I think

Comment: Yep, forgot there was no zero term. :)

Comment: The computations you've made have forgotten the term $i=1$. @Almot1960

Answer (score 3):

The "closed form" is $\frac{e \Gamma(n+1,1)}{n!} - 1$ where $\Gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).